# slider makes my rest layout disappear

Tags: android, xml, slider

I need your help! I want to insert a slider in my app. I have found the demo and it works fine. The thing is that when I want to insert it at my app I see only the slider and the rest of my screen is gone, like its invisible.

This is my xml for slider:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:orientation="vertical"

android:layout_width="fill_parent"

android:layout_height="fill_parent">



<Button

    android:id="@+id/button_open"

    android:layout_width="100dp"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"



    android:layout_centerInParent="true"

    android:visibility="gone" />



<com.my.android.app1.widget.MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer

    xmlns:my="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.my.android.app1"

    android:id="@+id/drawer"

    my:direction="bottomToTop"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    my:handle="@+id/handle"

    my:content="@+id/content">

    <include

        android:id="@id/content"

        layout="@layout/pen_content" />

    <ImageView

        android:id="@id/handle"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="40px"

        android:src="@drawable/sliding_drawer_handle_bottom" />

</com.my.android.app1.widget.MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer>
```

This was my previous lets say xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical" >



 <TextView

                android:id="@+id/Information"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_gravity="center"

                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

                android:text="info"

                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"

                android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is my new one:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"

            android:layout_height="fill_parent"

            android:orientation="vertical" >



         <TextView

                        android:id="@+id/Information"

                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:layout_gravity="center"

                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

                        android:text="info"

                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"

                        android:textStyle="bold" />

      <RelativeLayout

            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

            android:orientation="vertical"

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"

            android:layout_height="fill_parent">



            <Button

                android:id="@+id/button_open"

                android:layout_width="100dp"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content"



                android:layout_centerInParent="true"

                android:visibility="gone" />



            <com.my.android.app1.widget.MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer

                xmlns:my="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.my.android.app1"

                android:id="@+id/drawer"

                my:direction="bottomToTop"

                android:layout_width="fill_parent"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                my:handle="@+id/handle"

                my:content="@+id/content">

                <include

                    android:id="@id/content"

                    layout="@layout/pen_content" />

                <ImageView

                    android:id="@id/handle"

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                    android:layout_height="40px"

                    android:src="@drawable/sliding_drawer_handle_bottom" />

            </com.my.android.app1.widget.MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer>

        </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

any ideas why this is invisible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must play. If it doesn'y or you want something more complex change your first layout to Relative. it works for me!

Comment: Yes this one seems to play but me more complex one didn't. I changed it and ti worked. Thanks!